# Why am I getting symbol error for StackPane?

Tags: java, javafx

I have recently started on intelij a beginner in Javafx. I am getting this symbol error for stackpane and i have no idea why am i getting it. I have tried switching my jdk between 8, 9, and 10 still have the same problem.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.StackPane;

public class JavaFX1 extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        Button button = new Button("Click Here");
        primaryStage.setTitle("The Button");
        StackPane layout = new StackPane();
        layout.getChildren.add(button);
        Scene scene = new Scene(layout, 300, 600);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();

    }
    public static void main(String args[]){
        Application.launch(args);
   }
}
```

Comment: `StackPane` is in the `javafx.scene.layout` package.

Comment: Please also read https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326569/under-what-circumstances-may-i-add-urgent-or-other-similar-phrases-to-my-quest

Comment: The line `layout.getChildren.add(button)` will not compile. `getChildren` is a method not a field.

Comment: I really haven't any idea that stackpane is in layout package. Thats why I was suspecting its a jdk version problem. Because I had a previous issue with compiling a javafx program which I resolved by switching the jdk. Thanks for the comments.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing 
this:`layout.getChildren.add(button);` to this:`layout.getChildren().add(button);`